# Deploying resources to K8s cluster via Cloudify

Tags: cloudify

I am trying to deploy a resource to a kubernetes cluster via Cloudify UI, however I am getting the below error. Can anyone please help.

This is my blueprint.

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3

description: >
  This blueprint installs helm client, add repository to it and install
  chart(without values file and flags),using kubeconfig file content.
imports:
  - http://cloudify.co/spec/cloudify/5.0.5/types.yaml
  - plugin:cloudify-helm-plugin
  - plugin:cloudify-kubernetes-plugin?version= >=2.13.0

node_templates:
  sanity_pod:
    type: cloudify.kubernetes.resources.Pod
    properties:
      client_config:
        configuration: 
            file_content: { get_secret: **configuration_file_content** }
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          name: cloudify-nginx-withkubeConfig
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx:stable
```

The **configuration_file_content** is the kubeconfig file in yaml format (tried with json also) which has been uploaded to the **Resource** section in cloudify. During the deployment I am getting the below error.

```
[
  {
    "message": "string indices must be integers",
    "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/decorators.py\", line 285, in wrapper\n    authentication_property\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/client.py\", line 127, in __init__\n    prepare_api = api_configuration.prepare_api()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 34, in prepare_api\n    api = self._do_prepare_api()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 172, in _do_prepare_api\n    **self.kwargs\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 34, in prepare_api\n    api = self._do_prepare_api()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 109, in _do_prepare_api\n    os.path.expanduser(KUBE_CONFIG_DEFAULT_LOCATION)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 199, in __init__\n    self.set_active_context(active_context)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 250, in set_active_context\n    context_name = self._config['current-context']\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 611, in __getitem__\n    v = self.safe_get(key)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 608, in safe_get\n    return self.value[key]\nTypeError: string indices must be integers\n",
    "type": "TypeError"
  },
  {
    "message": "Error encountered",
    "type": "RecoverableError",
    "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/decorators.py\", line 285, in wrapper\n    authentication_property\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/client.py\", line 127, in __init__\n    prepare_api = api_configuration.prepare_api()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 34, in prepare_api\n    api = self._do_prepare_api()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 172, in _do_prepare_api\n    **self.kwargs\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 34, in prepare_api\n    api = self._do_prepare_api()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py\", line 109, in _do_prepare_api\n    os.path.expanduser(KUBE_CONFIG_DEFAULT_LOCATION)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 199, in __init__\n    self.set_active_context(active_context)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 250, in set_active_context\n    context_name = self._config['current-context']\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 611, in __getitem__\n    v = self.safe_get(key)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py\", line 608, in safe_get\n    return self.value[key]\nTypeError: string indices must be integers\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py\", line 411, in main\n    payload = handler.handle()\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py\", line 146, in handle\n    result = self._run_operation_func(ctx, kwargs)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py\", line 154, in _run_operation_func\n    return self.func(*self.args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/decorators.py\", line 295, in wrapper\n    causes=[generate_traceback_exception()]\ncloudify.exceptions.RecoverableError: Error encountered\n"
  }
]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: can you verify the secret value , maybe by doing a simple python snippet , yaml.safe_load ?

Comment: Thanks AhMaD AbUIeSa for your reply. Using the below snippet I am able to parse the yaml and it is returning the correct json response which is matching with my secret kubeconfig. This is snippet I am using for you reference.

`import yaml
with open("kconfig.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.safe_load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)`

Comment: one more thing that I see from the exception , does your kube_config have current-context value as part of the yaml ?

Comment: yes I have it. This is how my yaml looks like.

`apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: XXXXXX
    server: YYY
  name: ZZZ
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: XXX
    user: WWW
  name: QQQ
current-context: TTT
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: PPP
  user:
    client-certificate-data: XXX
    client-key-data: YYY
    token: ZZZ`

Comment: Hi @AhMaDAbUIeSa, any further suggestions?

Comment: the only thing that I can suggest is to add this to the plugin code ```self.logger.info('file_content: {0}'.format(file_content))```
by adding it on line 105 , in this file /opt/mgmtworker/env/plugins/default_tenant/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/2.13.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudify_kubernetes/k8s/config.py

Comment: The output is same as the kubeconfig content in json format!

Comment: how about the type of file_content , it should be dict , so in the log above , let's see the `type(file_content)`

Comment: It is not a dict. Showing <class 'str'>

Comment: Can we connect on slack or any other channel? Please let me know.

Comment: ok , so that is the issue , try adding the kubeconfig to secrets as json format

Comment: Tried adding the raw json and also tried uploading a json file, non of the approach is working. This is the json I am using.

`{"apiVersion": "v1","clusters": [{"cluster": {"certificate-authority-data": "XXX","server": "XXX"},"name": "XXX"}],"contexts": [{"context": {"cluster": "XXX","user": "XXX"},"name": "XXX"}],"current-context": "XXX","kind": "Config","preferences": {},"users": [{"name": "XXX",
      "user": {"client-certificate-data": "XXX","client-key-data": "XXX","token": "XXX"}}]}`

Comment: Hi @AhMaDAbUIeSa, any more suggestions on this?

Comment: Can you try the latest version of Kubernetes plugin , I believe there was a fix introduced for file_content there

https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-kubernetes-plugin/releases/tag/latest

Comment: Thanks a ton AhMaD AbUieSa! Updating the plugin version resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi AhMaD AbUIeSa, do you know on how to do a helm chart deployment using cloudify?

Comment: there is a helm plugin that you can use for that

Comment: Hi AhMaD AbUIeSa, any idea on how to upload a kubeconfig yaml file using cloudify's REST API. The following endpoint does not have anything which can upload a file to the Resource section within Secret.

curl -X PUT \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Tenant: <manager_tenant>" \
    -u <manager_username>:<manager_password> \
    -d '{"value": <new_secret_value>, "update_if_exists": false, "visibility": "<visibility>", "is_hidden_value": false}' \

Comment: well the rest api only takes the value as string , but in cloudify-cli , you can pass the file and the logic there will read the file and take care of that [ cfy secrets create key -f {file_path} ]